# Call a function in Javascript many times after a specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function in a endless loop after a specified time. For some reason setIntervall doesn't work. Here is a little example:

```
        function button_clicked() {
        clearInterval(interval)
        interval = setInterval(test(), 1000);
    }
    var i=1;
    function test(){
        $("#body").append("<h1>Hi"+i+"</h1>");
        i++;
    }
```

Only always when I click on the button (this button starts button_clicked) it writes Hi and the int in the output, but not after 1 second.
What do I wrong?

Comment: `setInterval(test, 1000)`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found this error in an hour ;)

Comment: Avoid using setInterval. Use requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout instead. That way you avoid overloading the call stack, especially for long running functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
setInterval(test(), 1000)
```

This calls `test` *immediately* and sets the interval to execute the *return value* of `test`, which is `undefined`.

In JavaScript functions are variables like any other.  Pass the variable (the function *reference*) to `setInterval`, not an execution of the function:

```
setInterval(test, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` takes a `function` as 1st parameter, and you're not passing it correctly, see:

```
interval = setInterval(test(), 1000);
```

replace with:

```
interval = setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Comment: Also can be fixed if the `test` function returned a function.

Comment: A technicality, but it takes a *function reference* not a function. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the parenthesis in your setInterval.

[Call a function in Javascript many times after a specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170681/call-a-function-in-javascript-many-times-after-a-specified-time/37170723#comment61876137_37170681)

Otherwise the function executes immediately